How can I detect when a car makes a turn using velocity vectors and account for speed?
I am trying to detect when a car makes a turn by analyzing its velocity vectors over time. Each velocity vector is represented as:
$$\vec{v_t} = (X_v, Y_v)$$
Currently, I calculate the change in direction $(\Delta \theta)$ between two consecutive vectors using the following formula:
$$\Delta \theta = \left( \arctan2(Y_{v2}, X_{v2}) - \arctan2(Y_{v1}, X_{v1}) \right) \quad \text{normalized to the range} \quad [-180^\circ, 180^\circ].$$
I classify a "turn" when the resulting change in direction exceeds a set threshold in degrees.
This approach works but has a major limitation: it doesn’t account for speed. At different speeds, the same change in direction can mean very different things:

At low speeds (e.g., $10 \, \text{km/h}$), a $90^\circ$ change in direction can occur quickly.
At high speeds (e.g., $100 \, \text{km/h}$), such a sharp turn is unlikely, and even smaller directional changes could indicate a turn.

I'm not sure how to tackle this problem completely, which is why I'm reaching out for help. Are there any formulas, resources, or specific calculations that I could use to improve this detection method? Specifically:

How can I incorporate speed into the calculation to better classify turns at different velocities?
Are there better approaches or criteria for detecting turns from velocity vector data?

I appreciate any guidance, resources, or suggestions you can provide. Thank you!

I think a missing information here is how long the transition between the two velocity vectors takes. Is it assumed to be smooth? Can it be as small as you want? This also greatly affects whether you'll classify the motion as a "turn" or just a slight deviation that can occur over a longer period of time.

The speed is the length of the velocity vector, assuming you didn't normalize it. If you did normalize it, the speed is the inverse of the normalization factor. You cannot define a turn only by comparing consecutive vectors, but, for example, also comparing every second, every third, and so on. For a car going in a mostly straight line, the deviations will cancel. For a car going around a corner, the deviations will amplify. However, if you have a practical application in mind, an accelerometer rigged to detect forces perpendicular to the direction of travel would be the better option.

What do you mean by "make a turn?" Why do you not know what condition you are trying to detect? On other, more practicality-oriented Stackexchange sites, we sometimes talk about the XY problem. That is when somebody wants to solve problem Y, and they imagine that if they could achieve X, then they could exploit that solution to solve Y. So, they ask how to solve X. But in reality, X is the wrong approach, and the question seems to make no sense to the people who want to offer help. Your question looks like it might be an XY problem.

Suppose I am driving on an express highway. I am approaching a gentle curve where, my direction of travel will continuously change over a span of one minute or more. There are no "exits" (no opportunities for me to leave the highway) anywhere along the curve. What problem do you think I would be able to solve if I could identify the exact location where my car "turned?"

There's also something peculiar about this question which is the mention of "velocity vectors", plural! I don't see an adequate reason to track the motion of a presumably rigid body, like an automobile, via multiple velocity vectors. Granted, the velocity vector of the COM can be decomposed into various components for useful purposes. But I'm not sure what are the different velocity vectors you're mentioning here and how the fact that there's more than one really affects the computations you're able to make in that context.

@Amit regarding your question about the transition times, currently they stand at 1 second intervals. but this may vary in the future. about your second reply. The plural is the series Vt. not several vectors per point in time.

@SolomonSlow when I say make a turn, I mean in a given time-frame, the car changed the direction its moving, as cars do. But I may have had to specify how many degrees it should be.
I don't believe its an XY problem . but I will admit, I myself am still trying to figure out all the parameters how to solve what I need, this is also a part of why i asked here, to get at least a direction.

Thanks for clarifying, @Aaron

@paulina unfortunately, I can only work with data I'm getting. I didn't normalize , how would normalizing help in this case?

@Aaron normalizing vectors helps because you can seperate the "direction" component from the "magnitude" component. The "magnitude" component then gives you the speed.

Check out the Frenet-Serret formulas (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet–Serret_formulas).
You have a parameterization of a curve (vs arc-length)
$$ {\bf r}(s) $$
and get the tangent unit vector:
$$ {\bf T} = \frac{{\bf r}}{ds}$$
and a normal vector:
$$ {\bf N} = \frac
{\frac{d{\bf T}}{ds}}
{||\frac{d{\bf T}}{ds}||}
$$
and then the bi-normal:
$$ {\bf B} = {\bf T}\times{\bf N} $$
So you moving object has an affixed "TNB" frame:

From here, you can define curvature and torsion (see figure) as well the usual velocity, acceleration and so on.

There are relations to, e.g. for the time derivatives of the ${\bf TNB}$, which I won't reproduce here.

Thank you! Calculating curvature was what i was looking for! I was able to reach a good solution thanks to it

If you decompose the velocity vector $\vec{v}$ into a speed $v$ and the direction of motion $\hat{e}$ with $$ \vec{v} = v \;\hat{e} \tag{1}$$
For example, at some instant i the position and velocity of the object is $$\begin{aligned} \vec{r}_i & = \pmatrix{ x_i \\ y_i } & \vec{v}_i & = \pmatrix{\dot{x}_i \\ \dot{y}_i } \end{aligned}  $$
The above is mostly stated to establish a consistent notation where the subscript i denotes the time frame, and the dots over the components are time derivatives. The time derivative of a position component is the velocity component along that direction.
So the decomposition is done with a cartesian to polar conversion
$$\begin{aligned}
 v_i & = \| \vec{v}_i \| = \sqrt{ \dot{x}_i^2 + \dot{y}_i^2 } \\
 \hat{e}_i & = \frac{1}{v_i} \vec{v}_i  =  \pmatrix{ \frac{\dot{x}_i }{ \sqrt{ \dot{x}_i^2 + \dot{y}_i^2 } } \\ \frac{ \dot{y}_i }{ \sqrt{ \dot{x}_i^2 + \dot{y}_i^2 } } }
\end{aligned}$$
Now if you know the acceleration vector $\vec{a}$ and you decompose it along the tangent direction $\hat{e}$ and its perpendicular $\hat{n}$ then you have $$ \vec{a} = \dot{v}\,\hat{e} + \frac{v^2}{\rho}\, \hat{n} \tag{2}$$
with $\dot{v}$ the change in speed, and $\rho$ the radius of curvature which is the desired calculation for this question.
This means that the change in speed and radius of curvature can be found from the following operations
$$\boxed{\begin{aligned}
  \dot{v}_i & = (\hat{e}_i \cdot \vec{a}_i) \\
  \frac{1}{\rho_i} & = \frac{ (\hat{n}_i \cdot \vec{a}_i) }{v_i^2}
\end{aligned}}$$
where $\cdot$ designates the dot product of two vectors $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b} = a_x b_x + a_y b_y$ and is used to project a vector onto a direction.
Now that for the velocity direction $\hat{e}_i$ shown above, the normal vector is
$$ \hat{n}_i = \pmatrix{ \frac{\mbox{-}\dot{y}_i }{ \sqrt{ \dot{x}_i^2 + \dot{y}_i^2 } } \\ \frac{ \dot{x}_i }{ \sqrt{ \dot{x}_i^2 + \dot{y}_i^2 } } } $$
It all comes together, once you can estimate the acceleration vector from the series of velocity vectors (and time frames).
The naïve way is to use finite differences, but this going to introduce a lot of noise into the calculation
$$ \vec{a}_i \approx \frac{ \vec{v}_{i+1} - \vec{v}_i }{\Delta t} $$
A slightly better approach that a lot of games use is to span two time frames
$$ \vec{a}_i \approx \frac{ \vec{v}_{i+1} - \vec{v}_{i-1} }{2 \Delta t} $$
The more scientific approach is to use a cubic spline interpolation which provides a smooth derivative.
$$ \begin{aligned}
 {\bf x}_{\rm spl} & = {\rm spline}( \pmatrix{t_1\\t_2\\ \vdots \\ t_n} , \pmatrix{\dot{x}_1 \\ \dot{x}_2 \\ \vdots \\ \dot{x}_n}) \\ 
 {\bf y}_{\rm spl} & = {\rm spline}( \pmatrix{t_1\\t_2\\ \vdots \\ t_n} , \pmatrix{\dot{y}_1 \\ \dot{y}_2 \\ \vdots \\ \dot{y}_n}) \\
\vec{a}_i & = \pmatrix{ {\rm slope}({\bf x}_{\rm spl},\,i) \\ {\rm slope}({\bf y}_{\rm spl},\,i) }
\end{aligned} $$
Where the functions ${\rm spline}$ and ${\rm slope}$ are implemented by the library, for example scipy.interpolate.
CubicSpline in python.

Thank you very much for the detailed answer, using cubic spline helped me with alot with the data interploation

The concept you are looking for is force. Force causes accelerations as in $F=ma$. Acceleration is the rate at which velocity vectors change.
A force in the direction the car is traveling (E.G. Stepping on the gas) will speed the car up. A force opposed to the direction (Stepping on the brake) will slow it down.
A sideways force will deflect the car sideways. You achieve this by turning the wheels. You now have to think about the forces between the tires and the road. These are friction forces.
If you try turning (or using the gas or brakes) on ice, nothing happens. The car keeps going the same direction at the same speed.
On the road, the tires roll forward but do not slip sideways. If the car tries to skid sideways, the road pushes back to keep that from happening.
If you turn the wheel, the road pushes the car in the new sideways-to-the-wheel direction and the car turns.
This might make more sense if you think about a ball tied to a fixed point with a rope. The ball travels around the point at constant speed. The rope pulls sideways on the ball, deflecting it from a straight line. There is no forward force so the ball does not speed up. There is no backward force so the ball does not slow down. The velocity continually changes direction, but has a constant magnitude.

As per the clarification in the comments, you're following (or in fact simulating) the motion of the car according to some constant time slices of size $\Delta t$. I think that a rather simple strategy you can employ to help you estimate whether the change in velocity induced a "turn" is the following:

Compute where the car would have been in the next frame, if it didn't change its velocity
Compute where the car would go now, by taking into account the new velocity vector
Subtract the resulting two position vectors to obtain a net displacement vector that the variation in velocity generated
According to the magnitude of the component of this displacement vector that's perpendicular to the previous velocity, decide if the deviation is large enough to count as a "turn".

Here's one way this can look like: assume our car is currently at some $\vec{r}(t)$, with some velocity $\vec{v}_1$. At the end of the current time slice $\Delta t$ it moves to:
$$ \vec{r}(t+\Delta t) = \vec{r}(t) + \vec{v}_1\Delta t $$
Now assuming the change in velocity occurred already by the end of this time slice, by now (at $t+\Delta t$) its velocity is $\vec{v}_2$. So at the next time slice it should be at:
\begin{align*} 
\vec{r}(t+2\Delta t) &= \vec{r}(t+\Delta t) + \vec{v}_2\Delta t 
\\ &= \vec{r}(t) + (\vec{v}_1 +  \vec{v}_2)\Delta t
\end{align*}
But now, let's calculate where it would have been, had it not changed its velocity. It's clear we get, naming that position $\vec{r}\ '$:
$$ \vec{r}\ '(t+2\Delta t) = \vec{r}(t) + 2\vec{v}_1\Delta t $$
So that the displacement generated by the change of velocity is $\Delta \vec{s}$ and given by:
$$ \Delta \vec{s} = \vec{r}(t+2\Delta t) - \vec{r}\ '(t+2\Delta t) =  (\vec{v}_2-\vec{v}_1) \Delta t$$
Now this displacement vector will have a component that's in the direction of $\vec{v}_1$, which is of less relevance, because you want to find out by how much the car strayed from that direction, in other words, find the displacement generated that's perpendicular to $\vec{v}_1$. We do that by some standard vector algebra. First calculate the displacement vector parallel to $\vec{v}_1$:
$$\Delta \vec{s}_{\parallel} = \frac{\Delta \vec{s}\cdot\vec{v}_1}{||\vec{v}_1||^2}\ \vec{v}_1,\tag{1}$$
where it should be clear that "$\cdot$" designates the vector dot product. Then, we need to compute the perpendicular component by subtracting this from $\Delta \vec{s}$. Now if you don't mind, here I've skipped a lot of nitty gritty vector algebra steps for a good reason I'll come back to. Take it for now that the result comes out:
\begin{align*}
\Delta \vec{s}_{\perp} &= \Delta \vec{s}-\Delta \vec{s}_{\parallel}  
\\[4pt]&= \frac{\vec{v}_1\times( \vec{v}_2 \times \vec{v}_1 )}{||\vec{v}_1||^2}\Delta t, \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Now, this last expression may be too complicated for what you'll end up needing. If you only end up needing the magnitude of the above we see that:
\begin{align*}
||\Delta \vec{s}_{\perp}|| &= \frac{1}{{||\vec{v}_1||^2}}||\vec{v}_1\times( \vec{v}_2 \times \vec{v}_1 )||\Delta t
\\[4pt] &= \frac{1}{{||\vec{v}_1||^2}} ||\vec{v}_1||\  || \vec{v}_2 \times \vec{v}_1 ||\Delta t
\\[4pt] &= \frac{1}{{||\vec{v}_1||}}  || \vec{v}_2 \times \vec{v}_1 ||\Delta t
\\[4pt]&= ||\vec{v}_2||\sin\measuredangle(\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2)\Delta t,
\end{align*}
where we've used the fact that $(\vec{v}_2\times\vec{v}_1) \perp \vec{v}_1$, as a property of the vector cross product.
Now, note that $\measuredangle(\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2)=\Delta \theta$, as per the $\Delta \theta$ in your question, but the way you compute this angle seems to be a bit inefficient. If you have two vectors like $\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{v}_2$ then the cosine of the angle they make is given by:
$$ \cos\measuredangle(\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2)= \frac{\vec{v}_1\cdot\vec{v}_2}{||\vec{v}_1||\ ||\vec{v}_2||}, $$
and obtaining the sine from this expression is straightforward.
Now, the reason I've skipped some steps in the above computation, is that we could reach the same result purely from geometry, as I try to show in the following diagram. But since you may want to use the actual vector $\Delta \vec{s}_{\perp}$ and not only its magnitude, I thought it is better to provide the expression for it as given in $(2)$ above. The diagram then corresponding to our setup is:

As I hope you see, the magnitude of $\Delta \vec{s}_\perp$ can be almost immediately read off from this diagram.
Now, to get a little bit into how you may decide whether this perpendicular displacement is large enough to count as a turn, one possibility is comparing it with the magnitude of $\vec{s}_{\parallel}$, as it is given in $(1)$. Then, a straightforward condition for counting as a turn could look something like:
$$||\vec{s}_{\perp}|| > k ||\vec{s}_{\parallel}||, \tag{3}  $$
with $k$ being some proportionality constant of your choice, and you may also adjust it according to the difference in speed $|v_2-v_1|$, I don't know if it needs to get this complicated though.
Now, while I think the above is a good strategy to apply for a single transition between frames, an additional technique you may want to apply is to test whether a condition as the one above is satisfied over more than a single frame.
In other words, suppose our car is driving on the highway and suddenly makes a momentary sudden turn to avoid an obstacle of some sort, hence immediately afterwards it resumes its previous constant direction along the highway. If we were to employ the above technique, we may count that as a "turn" that occurred for a very short while, which is fine, as the next instant we will no longer detect a turn.
However, if you want a "turn" condition to only be satisfied when the change of direction happens over longer periods of time, e.g. turning around a corner, driving a curved path, etc. then you may want to apply an additional condition such as "Turn condition $(3)$ was satisfied for a minimum of $n$ frames in succession" or something similar to that. This should be rather straightforward programmatically.
Hope all of this helps!
